# Usage issue in Electron app with WebAuthn keys created on web app

Tags: node.js, electron, webapi, webauthn

I have a web app where Two Factor Authentication can be configured. One option for the second factor is security keys (such as the Yubikey). For this, WebAuthn technology is used.

The problem occurred when trying to use created in web app keys for verification in an Electron app. I get arguments for `navigator.credentials.get` function via web API, but I get an error

`The relying party ID 'example.com' is not a registrable domain suffix of, nor equal to 'http://localhost:8080'`

Is there a way to get around this problem? Maybe there is a way to verify the key in Node.js via some library?

So far, I have come up with just opening a second window, in which a web app will be launched, do the verification, and then return control to the main window.